# how to send string value with popToViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am using navigationcontroller. i have (Root,A,B,C,D) class. i want to sand a string **test** value Class **D** to Class **A** via popToViewController.

Please give me suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationController) maintain the list of all pushed controller in [`viewControllers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) and the root controller always reside at `0`.

```
MyAController *myController = (MyAController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
myController.myText = @"My String" ;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to rethink your design, but since you haven't given enough information for me to suggest how, you could just try this:

```
A *aController = (A *)[myNavController rootViewController];
[aController setMyString:@"your string here"];
[myNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to achieve this.

1. Using [**Notifications**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW7).
2. Using [**Delegates**](http://css.dzone.com/articles/do-not-publishcreating-your).
3. Using [**Outlets/Properties**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW3).

Answer (score 1):

Make that string as property of class a then you need to access that object of the view A from navigation stack in class D.

And then access that property for using.

If Class A is rootView then jtbandes answers helps you otherwise pick it up from stack code some thing like this

```
if([self.navigationController.viewControllers count]>3)
             A *aController=(A *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-4];
```

if  your navigation is A->B->c->D

then you can access c by [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-2 similarly B by -3 A by -4.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a `ControllerA` instance var in your `ControllerB` and then pass the `ControllerA (self)` to `ControllerB`(ex: by a method) before call `pushViewController` from A to B. You can do the same from B to C...etc; i think the best solution is that of Jhaliya in case you want to work with navigationControllers.