# pass variable value by popToViewController in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, poptoviewcontroller

I have a variable "NameofCircle" on LocationVC ViewController and i have variable CName on this Controller i want to pass the  CName value to LocationVC Controller by popToViewController. I tried below code but did not get the result.

```
let viewControllers = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
    for aViewController in viewControllers
    {
        if aViewController is LocationVC
        {
           let Location = LocationVC()
            Location.NameofCircle = CName
    _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
            }
}
```

Comment: in here you need to go for custom protocols, or unwindsegue concept, google it once you get answer

Comment: Go for custom protocol. You can see this here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285588/how-to-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-view-controller-in-swift/39288232#39288232

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
let viewControllers = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
  for var aViewController in viewControllers
  {
  if aViewController is LocationVC
     {
        let aVC = aViewController as! LocationVC
        aVC.NameofCircle = CName
        _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aVC, animated: true)
     }
  }
```

**another choice To pass value to Root ViewController**

```
if let   myController  = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as? LocationVC
  {
    myController.NameofCircle = CName
   _ =  self.navigationController?.popToViewController(myController, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: I got this error because aViewController is a ViewController not Location VC "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'NameofCircle'"

Comment: is this correct aViewController = aViewController as! LocationVC

Comment: @RajeshkumarR - i am not tried , but this is wrong `aViewController = aViewController as! LocationVC`, one more question , is this possible we can directly send the value in  popToViewController

Comment: This way the value will not go to the parent viewController.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes. It is possible to send value in popToViewController. [See this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501991/7250862)

Comment: @unexpectedNil I have tried this and it worked. The value can be sent to any parent view controller without any problem.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR Now its clear. I also tried with this and it seems working. Thanks :)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have tried this and it worked. The value can be sent to any parent view controller without any problem.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR - if it is safer , it will go , ok one more question it will work in reverse engineering or storyboard reference concept

Comment: The question is that is it safe..??

Comment: I got "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on navigationController. Please help how to solve this problem.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers

Comment: Do you have navigation controller embedded in your view controller?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4,5**

You can use with code.

```
 let viewControllers = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
            for aViewController in viewControllers
              {
              if aViewController is SelectDeviceToGroup
                 {
                    let selecteDevicesVc = aViewController as! SelectDeviceToGroup
                    selecteDevicesVc.isEditSelected = true
                    selecteDevicesVc.selectedDevices = self.selectedDevicesIds
                    _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(selecteDevicesVc, animated: true)
                 }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your line :

_ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)

with this one:

_ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(Location, animated: true)

Comment: Got this Error "'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'"